# How to disable IBus in CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, ibus

There's a [conflict](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78860) with intellij IDEA for some reason.    I see lots of pages on how to disable it in ubuntu (system settings gui), but nothing for CentOS.

Comment: So…uninstall the ibus package?

Answer (score 1):

In Centos 7 you can select alternative input methods from a GUI using `im-chooser`or from the command line with `imsettings-list` to show available input settings and `imsettings-switch` to switch between them.